# How to remove border for last column in css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/93rvcobj/

I have created web page using `<table>`, i need to remove border-right for last column that is, remove the border-right for this table RV Roof Repair Boxes.

I tried like this

```
table.templateContainer>table:nth-child(3n){
        border:none;
    }
```

But it does not work, may i know, how to fix this?

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: just as a suggestion: your markup is unnecessarily complex and it can be replaced with simper and more semantic code

Comment: that is why i posted this question.. and it is not unnecessarily .thanks

Comment: If you still don't want to change the html stucture, then use the below css:  
`table.templateContainer tr td.columnsContainer:last-child table.templateColumn {
   border-right: none;
  }`

Comment: thank you so much for all your comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***CSS***

```
.columnsContainer:last-of-type .templateColumn{
    border-right:0px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/93rvcobj/3/)

Comment: thanks for your answer, and here is my another one fiddle link, in the same page http://jsfiddle.net/93rvcobj/6/ . may i know, how to show this text "Environmentally Friendly Protective Coatings" next to logo image? thanks.

Comment: @selva will it be k if alter the HTML.

Comment: i need like this http://s7.postimg.org/9mkz4pr3f/Untitled_2_copy.png .. can you help please?

Comment: thanks @Kawinesh SK: did you add any css? in your fiddle link?

Comment: ask it as question @selva ill say the answer clearly i cant explain in comment clearly.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work with my existing page. i think, only need to change my css.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can remove border like so:

```
.columnsContainer:last-child > table {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

You target the last column with `:last-child` and remove border in directly `table` child.

Answer (score 1):

change like this

```
table.templateContainer tr td:last-child table{
    border: none;
}
```